# 3D spaces in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a 3-dimensional subspace in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Find such $V_1, V_2, V_3, V_4$ that $$V_1 \cap V_2 \cap V_3 \cap V_4 = \{0,0,0,0\}$$.

I thought about such $V_i$ that 
$V_1 = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}
       1\\
       0\\
       0\\
       0\\
     \end{bmatrix}, 
     \begin{bmatrix}
       0\\
       1\\
       0\\
       0\\
     \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
       0\\
       0\\
       1\\
       0\\
     \end{bmatrix}  \right\}
$

And $V_2$ is the same, but the bottom line changes to 1, in $V_3$ it changes to 2 and in $V_4$ to 3. Am I thinking right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct assuming I'm interpreting what you've said in the right way. Essentially you're letting $e_i$ be the $i$-th standard unit basis vector, i.e.
$$e_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix},\ e_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0 \end{pmatrix} ,..., e_4 = \begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
and then letting
$$V_1 = \text{span} \{e_1, e_2, e_3 \},\ V_2 = \text{span}\{e_2,e_3,e_4\},\ V_3 = \text{span}\{e_1,e_3,e_4\},\ V_4= \{e_1,e_2,e_4\} $$
As such, for $v_1$ to be in $V_1$, its fourth coordinate must be $0$. Further, for $v_1$ to be in $V_1 \cap V_2$, both it's fourth and first coordinate must be zero. This goes on until we see that for $v_1$ to be in $\cap_{i=1}^4 V_i$ that all coordinates of $v_1$ must be $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, what I've said doesn't seem very clear as I read it now. Actually I meant something like that: V1 = {(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0)}, V2 = {(1,0,0,1), (0,1,0,1), (0,0,1,1)}, V3 = {(1,0,0,2), (0,1,0,2), (0,0,1,2)}, V4 = {(1,0,0,3), (0,1,0,3), (0,0,1,3)}.

Comment: @aaa That example you gave doesn't work: for example, $V_3 = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x_4 = 2(x_1 + x_2 + x_3) \}$, and then by combining similar descriptions for the others, $(1, 1, -2, 0)$ is in the intersection.  Overall, the intersection would be $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = x_4 = 0 \}$.

Answer (score 0):

You're working with vector spaces?

If so, then the idea will work.  Take a nice simple basis with four elements: $\{e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4\}$.  Let $V_n$ be the subspace generated by this basis with $e_n$ removed.

Comment: Hello. Yes, these are vector spaces. Actually I meant something like that: V1 = {(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0)}, V2 = {(1,0,0,1), (0,1,0,1), (0,0,1,1)}, V3 = {(1,0,0,2), (0,1,0,2), (0,0,1,2)}, V4 = {(1,0,0,3), (0,1,0,3), (0,0,1,3)}. And thank you for your answer!

Comment: I got your idea.  I just thought that my slight variation was a little neater.

Comment: Yes, your is very elegant. Thank you.